# Does CUDA work on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, blender, cuda

Has anyone tryed CUDA on Ubuntu 12.10 with Blender or another programm? In the last beta of Quantal CUDA wasn't working. I would like to update from 12.04 to 12.10 final but only if CUDA still works. Is there someone who already has experience with this? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The installation of CUDA 5.0 fails on ubuntu 12.10 :

```
$ uname -a
Linux yoyo-laptop 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:        12.10
Codename:       quantal

$ cd /opt

$ sudo wget -c http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/installers/cuda_5.0.35_linux_64_ubuntu11.10.run

$ md5sum cuda_5.0.35_linux_64_ubuntu11.10.run
dd82e9d1c5739806690c311e2f56c928  cuda_5.0.35_linux_64_ubuntu11.10.run

$ sha1sum cuda_5.0.35_linux_64_ubuntu11.10.run
bae5870868217bb0bc07d53a7e824301f9752e6a  cuda_5.0.35_linux_64_ubuntu11.10.run

$ sudo chmod +x cuda_5.0.35_linux_64_ubuntu11.10.run

$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc cc /usr/bin/gcc-4.5 50

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.4-1ubuntu2) 4.5.4

$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so /usr/lib/libglut.so

$ sudo ./cuda_5.0.35_linux_64_ubuntu11.10.run -verbose -optimus

Do you accept the previously read EULA? (accept/decline/quit): accept

Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 304.54? ((y)es/(n)o/(q)uit): y

Install the CUDA 5.0 Toolkit? ((y)es/(n)o/(q)uit): y

Enter Toolkit Location [ default is /usr/local/cuda-5.0 ]:

Install the CUDA 5.0 Samples? ((y)es/(n)o/(q)uit): y

Enter CUDA Samples Location [ default is /usr/local/cuda-5.0/samples ]:

Installing the NVIDIA display driver...

Verifying archive integrity... OK
Uncompressing NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 304.54...............................................................................................................................................................
Installing the CUDA Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-5.0.
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing NVIDIA CUDA..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Installation Failed
Toolkit:  Installation Failed
Samples:  Cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-5.0

Logfile is /tmp/cuda_install_30203.log
```

Comment: For Reference, it works following those instructions: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522699/installing-cuda-on-ubuntu/ (including changing gcc/g++ to use 4.6 [or older] and the soft link for the glut library otherwise you cannot install the samples; it's all documented on that page.)

Answer (score 1):

First install `gcc-4.4` and `g++-4.4` then make a symlink of `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc  /usr/bin/gcc-4.4`, it is not too clean but probably you should delete first the symbolic link of `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Comment: It worked for me with gcc-4.6. Any reason why you would choose 4.4?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is:

- install blender from repo for dependency purposes
- go to: http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/ and download zip archive
- unpack to /usr/local/blender-2.64
- start blender typing /usr/local/blender-2.64/blender

It detects then cuda gpu without any problems. (Of course assuming that you have propersly installed latest propietrary nvidia drivers)

Yep, i know that is not that elegant as making it work when installed from repo or ppa, but for me most important is that works, so i can use blender and cycles.

If you dont need the cuda toolkit (for develping etc) i think it is acceptable workaround for you too.